# How to update data into each row when click on button using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to update row data when user click on button but it updates all row of the table.

It updates all previous row when user click on another row's editbutton.

Each  **edit button** with row is keeping the same class.

**Sample Code**

```
    <table id="tablebody" class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th class=""> Code</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="form-control a medical_his" data-pk="medical_1" data-type="text">fffde</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="form-control a hcode" data-pk="hcc_1" data-type="text">101</div>
</td>
<td style="border:none;">
<button class="editbtn btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="form-control a medical_his" data-pk="medical_2" data-type="text">fffdefds</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="form-control a hcode" data-pk="hcc_2" data-type="text">fffdfasdddd</div>
</td>
<td style="border:none;">
<button class="editbtn btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
</td>

</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

**Working Example**  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93eTU/968/)

I want update a row which is clicked, not all previous clicked rows

Comment: i don't understand what is your problem, you already have working example !!

Comment: if user second time click on new edit button it update previous row with same data. How can we avoid it? and see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rebinding the click event on `#save_edit_info` each time an edit button is clicked. If you unbind this event when it has completed, it works fine.

Like this:

```
  $('#save_edit_info').click(function(){
      var medical_data1=$('#name').val();
      var hcc_data1 =$('#code').val();
      if(medical_data1 && hcc_data1)
      {
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');             
        row_h.html(hcc_data1);            
        row_m.html(medical_data1);            
      } else {
        alert("fields required");
      }
      $(this).off('click');
  });
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93eTU/969/)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand why you initialize `$('#save_edit_info').click(function()` in every edit button click. Initialize two click function separately.

**Script**

```
var row_h = '';
var row_m = '';

$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.editbtn').click(function(){ 
      $("#myModal").modal('show');  
      var row_medical_col=$(this).closest("tr");
      var row_medical_col_data=row_medical_col.find(".medical_his").text();
      var row_hcode_col_data=row_medical_col.find(".hcode").text();
      $('#name').val(row_medical_col_data);
      $('#code').val(row_hcode_col_data);
      row_h=$(this).closest("tr").find('.hcode');
      row_m=$(this).closest("tr").find('.medical_his');
   });

  $('#save_edit_info').click(function(){
      var medical_data1=$('#name').val();
      var hcc_data1 =$('#code').val();
      if(medical_data1 && hcc_data1)
      {
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');

        row_h.html(hcc_data1);

        row_m.html(medical_data1);
      }
      else
      {
          alert("fields required");
      }
  });

});
```

Take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39k3hzuc/

Comment: Thanks . sometimes do not see small mistakes ,I did mistake to  initialize each time when user click edit button.thanks again for correction.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone runs into my same issue

Get the index of the row clicked by finding the closest `<tr>`

```
var index = $(element).closest('tr').attr('data-index');
```

Then when you have the index you can call the updateRow function

```
$('#tableId').bootstrapTable('updateRow', {
    index: index,
    row: {
        id: id,
        name: name,
    }
});
```

This is the cleanest way to update a row

> Update the specified row(s), each param contains following properties:
>   index: the row index to be updated.  row: the new row data.

[Documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/)